# Close Stack Exchange chat banner by clicking anywhere

Tags: feature-request, design, notification-bar

To me, a little but convenient feature would be to close the "Welcome to the Stack Exchange network chat" banner by clicking anywhere (like the Next Badge menu, which has an X but closes with a random click) when you visit the [Stack Exchange network Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/).  Currently, you have to click the "Click here to remove the notification bar" in the screenshot below:

[image]

which is kind of hard to see, as it's gray, and so is the banner.
It is a small thing, but I think it'd be fairly useful.  Or if not that, maybe highlight the button in a brighter color to make it easier to see?

Or *maybe*, to prevent accidental one-click closure, you could double-click anywhere to close it, which would still be faster but completely intentional.

I await your opinions in the comments and answers below.

Answer (score 6):

I my opinion, if the banner disappears whenever the user clicks anywhere, there will be no option for those who want to keep it, at least for some time.

Like a user plans to read the banner, but before that, they click on something irrelevant to the banner, like a star. The banner disappears! *"What was written on it? Was it important?"* the user may think.

I know, they *could* just go read the FAQ for the chat rules, and find out what was on the banner. But some users are very new, and won't be sure where to look.

From @Rob (in deleted comments):

> Also some screens are long (and that banner is used for other chat
> notifications), so it's necessary for people to click on the banner,
> rather than dismiss it unseen by an accident.

**Conclusion: I think it might be better to highlight the button, so it would be easier to see. Or, enlarge the button, but not make it disappear *wherever* the user clicks on the screen.**

Comment: I think an even better idea is to have the banner disappear *only* if the user clicks somewhere where there is no button of click detector or something else related to clicking. For example, there's obviously no buttons or anything on the grey background in the chat page, so clciking there automatically can make it go away. If you're still afraid of accidental clicks or something, make it require double-click. Problem solved.

Comment: @mindstormsboi Misclicking is likely, and double-clicking would be unidiomatic. So, sorry, no, I don't agree.