# Add the ability to hide vote counts by clicking anywhere

Tags: feature-request, vote-count

I think a small improvement would be to have the ability to hide [vote counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) by clicking anywhere on the page or clicking again on the total number.  Currently, they only seem to disappear if I vote on the post, which doesn't happen on every post.

Like I said, it's a small improvement, but I think it'll be a nice cosmetic one.
What do y'all think?

Comment: This was [brought up on Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290172/11171084), but it's pretty old, so re-raising it here seems fair.

Comment: @Spevacus Only links from the same site appear there.

Comment: @Ollie But well, Oded's answer pretty much sums it all up, you can refresh the page or click at the question title (latter doesn't work for answers obviously).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but this would work for answers.

Comment: @Ollie Refreshing the page works for answers as well.

Comment: Clicking on the question title, does the trick.

Comment: You *really* like [clicking anywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350963/282094) to clear everything; a dozen requests later Ollie clicks [Post Question], and disappears. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Spevacus mentioned in [their comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352889/add-the-ability-to-hide-vote-counts-by-clicking-anywhere#comment1179610_352889), this feature-request was already brought up at Meta SO.

The status there is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), and I don't believe it will change much about that decision bringing it up here.

To cite [@Oded's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290173/1413395):

> Yes, you can refresh the page.
>
> Other than that there is no mechanism to "unsplit", nor do we see a reason to add such a mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

I raised a feature request many years ago on Meta SO to suggest that there should be a way to collapse the vote breakdown without reloading the page, specifically when the score is clicked again. (This has the advantage over hiding it when clicking anywhere in that you can have many scores expanded at once for easy comparison.)

Here is the question: [Can we toggle off the score breakdown without refreshing page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320620/6083675)

There’s no technical obstacle to this being done, only a lack of dev time. Several users came up with user scripts to solve the problem and posted them as answers to my question, which you could use yourself.